# Parametrize pytest test function based on output of setup_module or other function dynamically

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I have a pytest code in I have a setup_module in which I do some code processing which modifies a list of lists named testdata which is declared globally. I need to pass that list of lists to my test case dynamically based on what I receive from the setup_module.

```
testdata = [['servername_1', 'servermac_1', 'vlans'],['servername_2', 'servermac_2', 'vlans']]
 
def setup_module(module):
    #global testdata
    #do some steps
    #based on if the server has issues or server mac is different, 
    # return testdata which may or may not remove one or both list from test data(modified testdata)

def teardown_module(module):
    #close ssh connection

@pytest.mark.parametrize('servername, servermac, vlan', testdata)
def test_function(servername, servermac, vlans):
    for vlans in vlans:
       do ssh to servername:
          #do things
```

Anyway to dynamically parametrize the testdata in the test_function.

I have tried :

a) With the current code, even if setup_module removes one list from the testdata, since my test case is parametrized with testdata globally, which has two lists, the test cases runs twice for one list in testdata. I read from other questions that this is not possible as per pytest structure.

b) If i try the fixture by doing something like :

```
testdata = [['servername_1', 'servermac_1', 'vlans'],['servername_2', 'servermac_2', 'vlans']]

@pytest.fixture
def setup():
    #do some steps
    #based on if the server has issues or server mac is different, 
    # return testdata which may or may not remove one or both list from test data

def teardown_module(module):
    #close ssh connection


def test_function(setup):
    testdata = setup 

    for test in testdata:
        servername = test[0]
        servermac = test[1]
        vlans = test[2]

    for vlans in vlans:
       do ssh to servername:
          #do things
```

With this code structure, pytest doesn't consider it was two set of test cases but only one only set of case. Also, I can't use assert here, since if something fails for 1st servername and if i assert it to false, code won't run for 2nd servername at all.

Can somebody please suggest if I am doing something wrong here.
Apologies if didn't follow the question guidelines, since posting a question for the first time here.

Comment: Is the information needed in `setup_module` known at load time or only later? If the former, you could just call the function in your module directly.

Comment: Set up has a bunch of API calls which are triggered after the run is started.I tried calling the setup_module or the other function but it wasn't working for me. It was identifying 3 test cases instead of 2.

Comment: I added the answer for this case, please check it it works for you.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I tried the code you gave me. It is working for me but sort of partially. The reason i say that is, it gives me the test functions as you suggested, but when i modified my testdata variable in the setup_testdata() fixture, this change was not reflected in the parametrization. It only took the testdata variable value declared globally. Also, if in  setup_testdata() fixture, If i modify the testdata by removing vlans and some other parameter, it still shows vlans, which means the changes are not reflecting in the parametrization. Am i doing somethg wrong in expecting this

Comment: Sorry, my bad - you are right, this does not work, because `setup_testdata` is called too late. Will update the answer...

Comment: @MrBean Bremen - Hi, Does the below approach mean that I have to keep my calculate_testdata() in the conftest or in my test.py.

Comment: In this case it has to be in `conftest`, or in some other file imported by `conftest`. Note that you can have multiple `conftest.py` in different directories, that are related only to the directory and directories below.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the testcases at load time, you can parametrize your function in `pytest_generate_tests` at run time. To be able to set the test data before that, you have to use an initialization hook that is executed before `pytest_generate_tests`, like `pytest_configure` (which has to be put into a `conftest.py`). Here is a possible implementation:

*conftest.py*

```py
def pytest_configure(config):
    # save the testdata in the config, so you can access it from the hook
    config.testdata = calculate_testdata()
```

*test.py*

```py
def teardown_module(module):
    # close ssh connection

@pytest.hookimpl
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if all([name in metafunc.fixturenames
            for name in ("servername", "servermac", "vlans")]):
        metafunc.parametrize(("servername", "servermac", "vlans"), 
                             metafunc.config.testdata)

def test_function(servername, servermac, vlans):
    ...
```

In the case of your example testdata, this will generate the test functions:

```
test.py::test_function[servername_1-servermac_1-vlans] 
test.py::test_function[servername_2-servermac_2-vlans]
```